# Checking assumptions lmer/lme mixed models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, assumptions, lme4-nlme

I ran a repeated design whereby I tested 30 males and 30 females across three different tasks. I want to understand how the behaviour of males and females is different and how that depends on the task. I used both the lmer and lme4 package to investigate this, however, I am stuck with trying to check assumptions for either method. The code I run is

```
lm.full <- lmer(behaviour ~ task*sex + (1|ID/task), REML=FALSE, data=dat)
lm.full2 <-lme(behaviour ~ task*sex, random = ~ 1|ID/task, method="ML", data=dat)
```

I checked if the interaction was the best model by comparing it with the simpler model without the interaction and running an anova:

```
lm.base1 <- lmer(behaviour ~ task+sex+(1|ID/task), REML=FALSE, data=dat)
lm.base2 <- lme(behaviour ~ task+sex, random= ~1|ID/task), method="ML", data=dat)
anova(lm.base1, lm.full)
anova(lm.base2, lm.full2)
```

Q1: Is it ok to use these categorical predictors in a linear mixed model?
Q2: Do I understand correctly it is fine the outcome variable ("behaviour") does not need to be normally distributed itself (across sex/tasks)?
Q3: How can I check homogeneity of variance? For a simple linear model I use `plot(LM$fitted.values,rstandard(LM))`. Is using `plot(reside(lm.base1))` sufficient?
Q4: To check for normality is using the following code ok?

```
hist((resid(lm.base1) - mean(resid(lm.base1))) / sd(resid(lm.base1)), freq = FALSE); curve(dnorm, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is also that the version of lme4 I was using was not the most recent one and therefore the simple plot(myModel.lm) did not work, perhaps this is helpful for other readers to know..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Q1: Yes - just like any regression model.

Q2: Just like general linear models, your outcome variable does not need to be normally distributed as a univariate variable. However, LME models assume that the residuals of the model are normally distributed. So a transformation or adding weights to the model would be a way of taking care of this (and checking with diagnostic plots, of course).

Q3: `plot(myModel.lme)`

Q4: `qqnorm(myModel.lme, ~ranef(., level=2))`. This code will allow you to make QQ plots for each level of the random effects. LME models assume that not only the within-cluster residuals are normally distributed, but that each level of the random effects are as well. Vary the `level` from 0, 1, to 2 so that you can check the rat, task, and within-subject residuals.

EDIT: I should also add that while normality is assumed and that transformation likely helps reduce problems with non-normal errors/random effects, it's not clear that all problems are actually resolved or that bias isn't introduced. If your data requires a transformation, then be cautious about estimation of the random effects. Here's a paper addressing [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-985X.2005.00391.x/abstract).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to share my dataset and script for analysis including output to see if what I did is indeed correct. Is it possible in stack exchange? Furthermore I think I ran the wrong random factor (1|rat/task), shouldn't it just be (1|rat)? I tested 60rats (30 of each sex) on three tasks.

Comment: I tried the code for Q4 recently and I got an error about object of type 'S4' not subsettable. Was that code intended for models fit with the lme package? What about with lme4?

Comment: Regarding Q4, people making those plots need to keep in mind that the N for each of the plots produced will be substantially smaller than the total and therefore the plots will be much more variable. Don't expect them to look as consistently normally distributed as the overall.

Answer (score 17):

You seem quite mislead about the assumptions surrounding multi-level models. There is not an assumption of homogeneity of variance in the data, just that the residuals should be approximately normally distributed. And categorical predictors are used in regression all of the time (the underlying function in R that runs an ANOVA is the linear regression command).

For details on examining assumptions check out the Pinheiro and Bates book (p. 174, section 4.3.1). Also, if you plan to use lme4 (which the book isn't written around) you can replicate their plots using plot with an `lmer` model (`?plot.merMod`).

To quickly check normality it would just be `qqnorm(resid(myModel))`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you suggest using the lmer over the lme4 method? And am I right in understanding the response variable does not need to be normally distributed? I will have a proper read through the Pinheiro and Bates book.

Comment: Also, are you sure running qqnorm(resid(myModel)) on a mixed model with multiple factors works?

Comment: The newer lmer function has more capabilities and higher performance. Have you tried qqnorm? Follow the advice at the beginning of the book on how to read it.

Comment: The plot I had initially looked weird, possibly because I indeed did not have the newest version of lmer. Thanks for noting this, it now works as needed.

Comment: @John Are you making a distinction between the homogeneity of variance of the *raw* data vs. residuals? Or are you claiming there there is *no* equal variance assumption for linear mixed models at all? This site shows directly from Pinheiro and Bates that a residual vs. fitted values plot should be used to check for equal variance (see "(P&B Sect. 1.1.2) Assessing the Fitted Model"): http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/57937_f5aae15beace42c39a6c78d2ddd3ce15.html

Comment: I was just pointing out the residuals v. raw distinction. My guess is that since my answer is much older than the most recent edit of the question the author incorporated information making this answer superfluous at some later time. But also keep in mind that the link you refer to does not check an assumption of lmer. Nevertheless, one should always look at a plot like that for intepretation. (Fitted values and residuals can occur across multiple levels in lmer and a unidimensional plot like that couldn't be used to check it all)

Answer (score 16):

### Regarding Q2:

According to Pinheiro and Bates' [book](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387989570) you may use the following approach:

> "The `lme` function allow the modeling of heteroscesdasticity of the
>   within-error group via a `weights` argument. This topic will be
>   covered in detail in § 5.2, but, for now, it suffices to know that the
>   `varIdent` variance function structure allows different variances for
>   each level of a factor and can be used to fit the heteroscedastic
>   model [...]"
>
> Pinheiro and Bates, p. 177

If you would like to check for equal variances between `sex` you may use this approach:

```
plot( lm.base2, resid(., type = "p") ~ fitted(.) | sex,
  id = 0.05, adj = -0.3 )
```

If variances are different, you can update your model in the following manner:

```
lm.base2u <- update( lm.base2, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | sex) )
summary(lm.base2u)
```

Further more, you may have a look at the `robustlmm` package which also uses a weighing approach. Koller's [PhD thesis](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:6670/eth-6670-02.pdf) about this concept is available as open access ("Robust Estimation of Linear Mixed Models"). The abstract states:

> "A new scale estimate, the Design Adaptive Scale estimate, is
>   developed with the aim to provide a sound basis for subsequent robust
>   tests. It does so by equalize the natural heteroskedasticity of the
>   residuals and to adjust for the robust estimating equation for the
>   scale itself. These design adaptive corrections are crucial in small
>   sample settings, where the number of observations might be merely ﬁve
>   times the number of parameters to be estimated or less."

---

---

I do not have enough points for comments. I see however the necessity to clarify some aspect of  @John 's answer above. Pinheiro and Bates state on p. 174:

> *Assumption 1* - the within-group errors are independent and identically normally distributed, with mean zero and variance σ2, and
>   they are independent of the random eﬀects.

This statement is indeed not clear about homogeneous variances and I am not deep enough into statistics to know all the maths behind the LME concept. However, on p. 175, §4.3.1, the section dealing with *Assumption 1* they write:

> In this section, we concentrate on methods for assessing the
>   assumption that the within-group errors are normally distributed, are
>   centered at zero, and have **constant variance**.

Also, in the following examples "**constant variances**" are indeed important. Thus, one may speculate whether they imply homogeneous variances when they write "**identically** normally distributed" on p. 174 without addressing it more directly.

Answer (score -7):

Q1: Yes, why not?

Q2: I think the requirement is that the errors are normally distributed.

Q3: Can be tested with Leven's test for example.